# keytool not working for signing android app

Tags: android, google-play, signing, keytool

Ok I am trying to follow the steps on google's website on how to prepare an app for putting on their market. My problem is when I am trying to use keytool.... this is beyond frustrating...

This is exactly what I am doing.

Right click->open cmd here (Java/jdk1.70_09/bin)

then I type in the cmd:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

which is the example on google's site. I type in "password" for my password and enter my info it asks me. It then gives me this error that I have tried searching for and no luck:

```
[Storing my-release-key.keystore]
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: my-release-key.keystore (Access is
 denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: my-release-key.keystore (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:1152)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
```

I need help from anyone who has done this before! I'm sure I'm doing something simple which is the most frustrating part...

I'm using Eclipse 4.2.1 and Windows 7 64bit  if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can do it with eclipse please follow the steps :

1) Go to File menu --> Click on Export 
 2) Next Select to choose export Destination --> Android --> Export Android Application 
 3) Click Next browse your project -- > click Next
 4) Select **keystore** --. you have two options 
    (i) Use existing Keystore
    (ii) Create new Keystore
 5) Select (ii) option to create new keystore

Now browse the location where you want to store your Keystore file and also password
 6) Click Next and enter you details as per field mentioned and click next
 7) Now Save the destination .APK file which is signed.
 8) Now click Finish.

Comment: Wow, can't believe it was that simple. For whatever reason I didn't think create new keystore was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like keytool is trying to create the file `my-release-key.keystore` but is unable to as you don't have write access to the working directory (which I take it is `Java/jdk1.70_09/bin`).  Try specifying a full path for the keystore file somewhere you have write access, e.g. within your home directory (`Users\<your account>`).

Comment: Just specify a full path in place of `my-release-key.keystore`, i.e. `keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\slowsword\my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 ` (replace slowsword with your Windows user name).